# Understanding the proof of Fuglede's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

I am trying to understand this proof of Fuglede's theorem on wikipedia :

[image]

Everything was making sense until the last sentence: "Considering the first-order terms in the expansion for small λ, we must have $M^*T = TN^*$." What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have shown that $F(\lambda)\equiv T$. Let’s (carefully!) expand $F$ as a series around $\lambda\approx0$: $$F(\lambda)=T+\lambda M^{\ast}T-\lambda TN^{\ast}+\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$$Which implies that: $$\lambda(M^\ast T-TN^\ast)=\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$$You can divide away by $\lambda$ and safely take limits as $\lambda\to0$ to conclude $M^\ast T-TN^\ast=0$.

N.B. You can induct to obtain equality of all higher order terms as well, although this gets more complicated and probably less interesting.

Comment: Thank you. I just have a quick question about the big O symbol here. $\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$ just means that $\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$ approaches 0 as $\lambda$ approach 0 even when we divide by $\lambda^2$ right?

Comment: @Bill See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for a full list of related notations. Actually Big-O means that dividing by $\lambda^2$ gives me a finite nonzero number in the limit; this implies necessarily that the limit dividing by just $\lambda$ is $0$. The property you described is *little*-o.

Comment: I need to make a correction. Big-O allows for the possibility of the limit being zero. It is Big-Theta notation which means the limit (or the liminf, limsup) are both finite and nonzero, but we generally use little-o when the limit is 0, for emphasis